# Can't run-app on Grails

Tags: grails

I just installed Groovy 2.0.1 and Grails 2.1.0.

Was following the instructions on how to create a simple Hello World web app on:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication

When I tried to run the app, I got the following error:

grails> run-app

```
| 
Compiling 113 source files
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    | Running Grails application
    | Error 2012-07-27 17:05:41,773 [pool-4-thread-1] ERROR core.ContainerBase
      - A child        container failed during start
Message: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/helloworld]]
    Line | Method
    ->> 222 | innerGet in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync

Caused by LifecycleException: Failed to start component 
   [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/helloworld]]
    ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync

Caused by NoSuchMethodError:  
 javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
    ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
    |   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    |   908 | run      in     ''
 ^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
    | Error 2012-07-27 17:05:41,869 [main] ERROR core.ContainerBase
    A child container failed during start

   Message: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
  [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
  Line | Method
  ->> 222 | innerGet  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
  |    83 | get       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
  |   137 | doStart . in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.InlineExplodedTomcatServer
  |   102 | start     in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServer
  |   176 | doCall .  in RunApp$_run_closure5_closure12
  |   153 | doCall    in RunApp$_run_closure5
  |   121 | runInline in RunApp
  |    67 | doCall    in RunApp$_run_closure1
  ^    33 | doCall .  in     ''

  Caused by LifecycleException: Failed to start component
  [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
  ->> 303 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync

  |   138 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
  |   886 | runTask . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
  |   908 | run       in     ''
  ^   680 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

  Caused by LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
  ->> 303 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync

  |   138 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
  |   886 | runTask . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
  |   908 | run       in     ''
  ^   680 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
  | Error Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]] 
   (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
at
   org.grails.plugins.tomcat.
      InlineExplodedTomcatServer.doStart(InlineExplodedTomcatServer.groovy:137)
at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:102)
at RunApp$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(RunApp:176)
at RunApp$_run_closure5.doCall(RunApp:153)
at RunApp.runInline(RunApp:121)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp:67)
at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
  [StandardService[Tomcat]]
... 7 more
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
  [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
... 7 more
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
... 7 more
  | Error Server failed to start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
  | Error Error running script run-app: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
  (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

What am I possibly doing wrong? This tutorial didn't specify to set up a config for tomcat anywhere?

Comment: it uses an embedded tomcat instance that is downloaded from the main grails repo. Are there any tomcat instances in your classpath? What about other xml libraries? What happens when you try to run it outside of the shell with a different port ( grails -Dserver.port=9090 run-app ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@tomas You were right! The switching to a different port suggestion didn't work. I worked perfectly after removing the following jars from my CLASSPATH. It looked like this in .bash_profile:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:"$TOMCAT_HOME/common/lib/servlet-api.jar":"$TOMCAT_HOME/common/lib/jsp-api.jar";
```