# ScriptExitException after tests pass in grails 2.3.8

Tags: unit-testing, grails

**Edit:** *I can no longer reproduce this issue. The root cause remains a mystery to me.*

When running grails test-app on a very small sample project with 2 unit tests, the tests all PASS but I get an error message afterwards:

```
grails> test-app
| Running without daemon...
...............................................
|Compiling 1 source files
.
|Running 2 unit tests...
|Running 2 unit tests... 1 of 2
|Running 2 unit tests... 2 of 2
|Completed 2 unit tests, 0 failed in 0m 7s
.................
|Tests PASSED - view reports in C:\src\grails238-test\target\test-reports
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=C:\Users\rmorrise -Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPe
rmSize=384M
| Error Error running script test-app: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (Use --sta
cktrace to see the full trace)
```

If it's an error in my code, can anyone give me a hint of what to look for?

--stacktrace output and test Spec code follow.

```
| Error Error running script test-app --stacktrace: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitExcepti
on (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:98)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(
GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(
GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBindin
g.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBindin
g.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:32)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(
GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(
GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBindin
g.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBindin
g.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
| Error Error running script test-app --stacktrace: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitExcepti
on
```

Here are my two test specs:

BookSpec:

```
package grails238.test

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(Book)
class BookSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test foo"() {
        when:
            domain.title = "Foo"
        then:
            domain.title == "Foo"
    }
}
```

BookControllerSpec:

```
package grails238.test

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(BookController)
class BookControllerSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test foo"() {
        when: "index"
            controller.index()
        then: "expect nothing"
            controller.response.contentAsString == "Hello World"

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713839/cant-run-app-on-grails . Can you check the CLASSPATH?

Comment: @dmahapatro: Thanks for the comment. I looked at that question; but, the error message on that other question doesn't match mine and there is no %CLASSPATH% configured in my cmd line environment. I also don't see any reference to my existing tcServer installation on my PATH.

Answer (score 3):

With grails 2.3.5 and 2.3.8 on windows, this can be fixed by editing "scripts/_GrailsTest.groovy".

Line 97:

```
if(exitCode != null) {
```

should be replaced with

```
if(exitCode != null && exitCode != 0) {
```

Reference:
https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10809

Answer (score 0):

It might be also possible , if you have deleted the Test file generated for your script . Generated under test/cli/